# Apex SOQL Relational Query

Tags: apex, soql

I have Below Query From Parent Id to child, but getting the below error. Please help me out with this one.

Query

```
Select id,
       (Select id,Type__c,Document_Attached__c,Opportunity__c from Top_X_Designation__r), 
       Handoff_Attached__c 
from Opportunity
```

Error I am getting

> Document_Attached__c,Opportunity__c from Top_X_Designation__r),
>                                            ^
>   ERROR at Row:1:Column:71
>   Didn't understand relationship 'Top_X_Designation__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Both the object Opportunity(Parent) Top_X_Designation__c(Child) having Lookup relationship.

Comment: Are you sure that the relationship name is `Top_X_Designation__r`?

Comment: @JayantDas not sure Please let me know how to find out!!

Comment: Take a look at [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_parent_child.htm) which describes how you can find the relationship names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *always* find the child relationship name by going through the `DescribeSObjectResult` on your parent object.

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Opportunity.getChildRelationships())
{
    system.debug(relation);
}
```

Typically, the relationship name will be plural, so the correct name is likely `Top_X_Designations__r`.